# Netbeans end of line character

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I have a problem with Netbeans editor. A weird character appears at end of the each line.

Netbeans version : 7.3

Here is the ss : https://i.stack.imgur.com/E38fH.png

I searched for lots of websites for this problem and I cant find any solution.

Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are 'Non-printable characters'.

You only have to disable them in View -> Show non-printable characters

Comment: Oh sir, really thank you. I am very sorry for this time stealing.